# How to join two tables using left join with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join two tables using left join on multiple conditions.

I have two STS_CD flags `AC` or `IA`.

I want to get data where `STS_CD='AC'` but i got it on both `AC` or `IA`.

My Query is:

```
SELECT `bldr`.`id`     AS `bldr_ID`, 
       `bldr`.`sts_cd` AS `bldr_STS_CD`, 
       bldr.shrt_nm 
FROM   `bldr` 
       LEFT JOIN `bldr_img` 
              ON `bldr`.`id` = `bldr_img`.`prnt_id` 
                 AND `bldr_img`.`img_cat_cd` = 'LG' 
                 AND `bldr`.`sts_cd` = 'AC' 
                 AND `bldr_img`.`sts_cd` = 'AC' 
ORDER  BY `bldr`.`id`
```

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: The join doesn't make any sense because you don't select any column from `bldr_img` table. All you can achieve this way is to duplicate some rows from `bldr` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT bldr.ID as bldr_ID, bldr.STS_CD AS bldr_STS_CD,bldr.SHRT_NM
FROM bldr LEFT JOIN
     bldr_img
    ON bldr.ID = bldr_img.PRNT_ID AND
       bldr_img.IMG_CAT_CD = 'LG' AND
       bldr.STS_CD = 'AC' AND
       bldr_img.STS_CD = 'AC'
ORDER BY bldr.ID;
```

When using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *second* table should go in the `ON` clause.  Conditions on the first table should be in the `WHERE` (except for the `JOIN` condition, of course).  So try this:

```
SELECT bldr.ID as bldr_ID, bldr.STS_CD AS bldr_STS_CD,bldr.SHRT_NM
FROM bldr LEFT JOIN
     bldr_img
    ON bldr.ID = bldr_img.PRNT_ID AND
       bldr_img.IMG_CAT_CD = 'LG' AND
       bldr_img.STS_CD = 'AC'
WHERE bldr.STS_CD = 'AC'
ORDER BY bldr.ID;
```

Why?  Although this seems arcane it makes perfect sense.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first tables *regardless* of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true, false, or even `NULL`.  It doesn't "know" whether the condition is on the first table or the second.  Hence, filters on the first table are not effective.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way to strong on mysql queries ? Any reference links